# Convert list of tuples to tensorflow dataset (tf.data.Dataset)

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets, tf.data.dataset

Data from kaggle Natural Language Processing with Disaster Tweets

```
ds_train

>>>[("Already expecting to be inundated w/ articles about trad authors' pay plummeting by early next year but if this is true it'll be far worse",
  0)
 ('@blazerfan not everyone can see ignoranceshe is Latinoand that is All she can ever benothing morebut an attack dog 4 a hate group GOP',
  0),...]
```

`

like [(X1 , y1),...(X_n , y_n)]

OR dataframe

```
0                      Just happened a terrible car crash

1       Heard about #earthquake is different cities, s...

2       there is a forest fire at spot pond, geese are...
```

I want to convert it to tensorflow datasets.
I tried `tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(ds_train)` but got error

> ValueError: Can't convert Python sequence with mixed types to Tensor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to split the tuple:

```
import tensorflow as tf

data = [("Already expecting to be inundated w/ articles about trad authors' pay plummeting by early next year but if this is true it'll be far worse", 0), ('@blazerfan not everyone can see ignoranceshe is Latinoand that is All she can ever benothing morebut an attack dog 4 a hate group GOP', 0)]
x, y = zip(*data)
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((list(x), list(y)))
```

With a dataframe:

```
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((df['text'], df['target']))
```

Comment: Your code worked!